# Find a number that is 9 times bigger than total of its digits?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Find a number $X$ that is 9 times bigger than the total of its digits: for example if $X=abc$, then $X=9*(a+b+c)$.

I don't know the number of digits; it could be 3 or 2 or more.

Answer (score 11):

Simple 2 digit answer will be,

> $81$

For 2 digit number,

> $X = ab = 10a + b = 9*(a+b)$
> We have, $a = 8b$ 
> Only $b = 1$ satisfies the condition for $X$ to be $2$ digit number.

3 digit answer is not possible.

> $X = abc = 100a + 10b + c = 9a + 9b + 9c $
> i.e. $91a = 8c - b$ 
> $a$ can take values from $1$ to $9$, not zero 
> But max of $c$ is $9$, so RHS is always less than or equal to $72$.
> Hence, no possible $3$ digit answer.

Answer (score 7):

While Rajendra is right, the only "normal" solution is 81...

Another solution is zero. The sum of its digits is zero, and zero times nine is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete Rajendra's answer, I show that there's no solution with *more* than 3 digits either, so that the only possible solutions are

> 81 and 0.

Assume there's a solution with $n$ digits where $n>2$. We have:

> $X = a_1a_2\dots a_n = 10^{n-1}a_1 + 10^{n-2}a_2 + \dots + a_n = 9a_1 + 9a_2 + \dots + 9a_n $ gives $10^{n-1}-9\leq(10^{n-1}-9)a_1 = 8a_n - a_{n-1} - 91a_{n-2} - \dots - (10^{n-2}-9)a_2\leq72.$

So there's no possible answer with more than 2 digits.

Comment: You should explain how you found 81 and prove there's no other 2 digit number.

Comment: @warspyking Rajendra already did that - I didn't want to pinch his work!